# Flash drive webserver

Tags: angularjs

Hopefully someone here can help me out.

Currently I have a small AngularJS app. I want to put this on an USB drive and make it very easy to run. The idea is someone can just plug in the drive click a file and run the app. I've been thinking about using node for this and then make a little script that would start the server and app. So people can click the script and the app runs. The problem is however (afaik) you need to have node installed on the computer which can't be done.

The client hasn't got his webserver running and still want to run the app. So please don't tell me why would you make an angular app and wanna run it without webserver.

Hopefully anyone has any solution or idea to make this work.

So in short:

AngularJS Application on USB
Plug in the USB, click a file and run the app in the browser.

Thanks for reading and thinking with me.

Comment: Do you need webserver or not?

Comment: I need to run the angular app. I'm using ui.router and would preferable like to use LocalStorage.

Comment: So I guess I need a webserver for that right?

Comment: Do you have a webserver right now? We don't know your requirements.

Comment: Please read the post properly and not just comment to get credits. I've stated I do NOT have a webserver

Comment: It seems like you not sure what you need. If you don't have a server and your angular app works then what is the problem? Why are you thinking about using node?

Comment: The app doesn't work using the file:/// protocol. However, it works on a server. The problem is the client hasnt got a server running atm but still want to use the app during some presentations. The app shows videos and between them it does a little quiz and stores results to show at the end. It will become available on a server in the future tho.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered running a standard web server on the USB Stick?

I see that you have suggested Node, but another alternative could be to use XAMPP?

[XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org) is a completely free, easy to install Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP, and Perl. The XAMPP open source package has been set up to be incredibly easy to install and to use.